# Browsing by DNS name not working, everything else is

Tags: domain-name-system, proxy, mac

Running on a Snow Leopard MacBook air, can't browse the web (in any browser, tried FF,Chrome,Safari) using DNS names that are either already cached in DNS or not. Browsing to google.com or thisisnotincache.com both result in the browser reporting a "not connected to the internet" page. Ok, DNS resolution we're all thinking...nope. Terminal I can ping, trace, nslookup, and everything else all of these DNS names (those that exist in cache, those that don't, flushing cache, etc. all still resolve just fine) on all DNS servers. Still, browsing in a web browser DOES work if I use actual IP's as the address rather than a DNS name (i.e. http://72.14.204.105) works just fine.  Even more odd, I pull up Terminal and try using Curl to "browse" by DNS name, and that works just fine (in addition to by IP).

I've triple checked proxy settings (and none are being used anywhere on any network), I've tried using different DNS servers, I've removed all filter drivers that were there (i.e. software VPN, Firewalls, etc.), and turned of nearly everything I can think of that would even remotely possibly contribute to anything.

Naturally, I'm now running a malware/virus scan to be thorough, but that's been running for an hour with nothing found yet, though who knows.

[EDIT]: Some additional info in response to comments. Yes, rebooted, no luck. Verified proxy settings (no proxies anywhere, OS level, browser, etc.). Other applications are working fine (skype, dropbox, email apps, etc.).  Literally, all I can seem to find that isn't "working" is browsing the web with any web browser by DNS name.

Comment: What does `nslookup google.com` say? Did you try with a command line web browser: `links`, `lynx`, ...?

Comment: nslookup works fine (see above), didn't try any of those cmdline browsers, but did work fine with CURL (see above). I'll try one of those for kicks...I'll try anything at this point.

Comment: Have you rebooted?  That can resolve issues with mDNSResponder

Comment: , especially after a suspend state.  You can also try sudo killall mDNSResponder

Comment: do you by any chance have a sonicwall vpn client installed on your machine?

Comment: not that I know of, I'll check (this is a company user's laptop). If they do, would have had to install it themselves, but that's certainly reasonable. Did have a Cisco VPN client installed that I removed with no luck, but I'll check

Comment: Off topic? you've got to be kidding me? I'd say it covers networking and desktop infrastructure pretty well.

Comment: I voted to have it moved to superuser for what it's worth.  You never answered my question about the sonicwall vpn client.

Answer (score 1):

Because it doesn't work with multiple browsers ..

- Did you checked the proxy settings at the OS GUI level ?
- I guess you tried to logoff from your session already ?
- What about email application / ftp client / etc ?

Comment: Yep, tried those...good points though, just added info to the question.